# Why does reverse() not change my array?

Tags: perl, push, reverse

When I use `reverse()` or `sort()`, I always need to save the return statement into a variable if I want to use it later.

```
@array=qw(Nick Susan Chet Dolly Bill);
@array = reverse(@array);
```

Why is this different from using `push()`, `pop()` or `shift()` where you can just call the function and the array will be changed?

```
@array=qw(Nick Susan Chet Dolly Bill);
push(@array, "Bruce");
```

So what exactly is the difference between these "functions"?

Comment: The answer could be, so that you can chain `grep,sort,map,reverse`. If you're concerned about verbosity you can `@$_ = reverse @$_ for \@array` but I would refrain from it.

Comment: Thank you, it sounds like you know the answer but I don't understand it.

Comment: Because `reverse` (like `sort`, `grep`, `map` and others) work on **lists**, whereas `push`, `pop`, `shift` and `unshift` work on **arrays**. Arrays are not lists.

Answer (score 14):

[`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) provides a major clue:

> Functions for real @ARRAYs
>
> [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html),
>   [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html),
>   [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html),
>   [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html),
>   [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html),
>   [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html),
>   [`unshift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html),
>   [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html)
>
> Functions for list data
>
> [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html),
>   [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html),
>   [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html),
>   [`qw//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qw.html),
>   [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html),
>   [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html),
>   [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)

---

And [`perldoc perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f) explains the difference between arrays and lists (emphasis my own):

> ### What is the difference between a list and an array?
>
> (contributed by brian d foy)
>
> A list is a fixed collection of scalars. An array is a variable that
>   holds a variable collection of scalars. An array can supply its
>   collection for list operations, so **list operations also work on arrays**
>
> ...
>
> **Array operations**, which *change* the scalars, *rearrange* them, or
>   *add* or *subtract* some scalars, **only work on arrays**. **These can't work on a list**, which is fixed. Array operations include
>   `shift`, `unshift`, `push`, `pop`, and `splice`.

---

In short, list operations like `reverse` are designed for lists, which cannot be modified.

The fact that they can accept arrays is merely a side-effect of list support.

Comment: In other words, you can `reverse(qw(Nick Susan Chet Dolly Bill))` but you can't `push(qw(Nick Susan Chet Dolly Bill), "Bruce")`

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
@array = reverse(@array)
```

I probably wouldn't recommend this, but if you really wanted to you could fix it...:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use subs 'reverse';

my @array=qw(Nick Susan Chet Dolly Bill);

sub reverse(\@) {
  my $a = shift;
  @{$a} = CORE::reverse(@{$a})
}

reverse(@array);
print Dumper \@array;

#$VAR1 = ['Bill','Dolly','Chet','Susan','Nick'];
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can just assign it to the same array. But why do I have to assign it to an array (the same one or an other one, doesn't matter). Because when I use pop(), I can just say:

    pop(@array);

And the array will be changed without me having to assign it to anything.

Comment: Except that now `reverse` will not work with lists : `my @array = reverse(1..6); print Dumper \@array;` returns `Type of arg 1 to main::reverse must be array (not null operation)`

Comment: Aaah yes, except for that! :-)  I did say I didn't recommend it!